# How to remove hidden attribute of a folder in windows?

Tags: powershell

I mistakenly turned C:\Users\User into a hidden folder. Now, a lot of my programs aren't running. I can't even open file explorer. I managed to open powershell in admin mode, but am able to see the hidden folders using ls - Force. However, I don't know how to unhide them. How to I remove the the hidden attribute so that the mode of the folders change from d--h-- to d-----?

Comment: you can use `Get-Item` to grab the dirinfo for that dir. then you can assign the `.Attributes` property just the value `'Directory`. that will remove all but that attribute from that dir.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [Lee_Dailey points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68517861/how-to-remove-hidden-attribute-of-a-folder-in-windows#comment121091338_68517861), you can edit the `Attributes` property value on the corresponding `DirectoryInfo` object.

Since `Attributes` is a `Flags` enum (or a *bit field* if you will), the easiest way to remove a flag is to use [bitwise operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators#bitwise-operators):

```
$folder = Get-Item C:\Users\User -Force
$folder.Attributes = $folder.Attributes -band -bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden
```

This will set the value of `Attributes` to whatever it already is, but excluding the `Hidden` flag regardless of whether it was set or not

Answer (score 4):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68519217/45375) shows how to use PowerShell-native commands to solve your problem, but on occasion it is easier to call an *external program* to do a simple job, which is the standard [`attrib.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib) utility in this case:

```sh
# Remove (-) the hidden (h) attribute from the specified dir.
attrib -h C:\Users\User
```

Note: Hypothetically speaking, if the target file or directory also has the *system* (`s`) attribute set - which you shouldn't modify yourself, and it is similarly ill-advised to change the hidden status of true system files - you would need `attrib -s -h ...` in order to turn off the hidden attribute (you could then restore the system attribute with `attrib +s ...`).